# What are the contract management software solutions that are affordable, secure, scalable, and also simple? US Origin preferred

Tags: software-testing, business-intelligence, contract-manager

Contract management is becoming a headache while remote working. It was tough earlier too but remote working made it almost impossible. we need a software solution that is light, at the same time very practical in managing our contracts, signing it, storing everything in an organized manner, etc. It shouldn't be very complex, even if features are less, it should be user friendly and easy to handle.

I would like to get some new suggestions that are innovative, and even some suggestions to handle contracts effectively while remote working.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same a year back. Started working with **Contractify** back then and honestly couldn't do without it anymore now.

- Integration went really easy,
- the user experience is fluent
- and finally, have a clear overview of all contracts & what to do with them at any time... online :D

The company behind the software also offers contract management services, where they just register & manage contracts for you. Thinking of looking into that option as well as they really seem to know how to best handle contracts & their customer support is superb :) Here's the link to their website I found online: https://www.contractify.io/ Hope this helps!